# Apps Script Installable Trigger Not Firing

Tags: google-apps-script

## Description

My previously functioning Google Apps Scripts that had time-based triggers installed on them have stopped working as of Feb 7, 2024. The only error I get in the daily emailed logs is:

> Authorization is required to perform that action.

When I run the script manually it functions as intended.

Even setting up a simple function such as in the code section below, and setting a time-based trigger to run every minute, doesn't work. There are no logs that are found in the Apps Script project, seemingly the script never runs, but I do continue to receive emails stating:

> Authorization is required to perform that action.

## Code

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log('Testing...')
}
```

Has something changed with respect to the time-based triggers? Am I missing a new required authorization to run time-based triggers?

Comment: Have you set the authorization scopes in `appsscript.json` explicitly?  If you get `Authorization is required to perform that action.` in the logs, it means that the timed trigger works but it tries to perform a call that the script does not have permission for.  It can happen if you have set scopes explicitly but later added some call that requires another permission.

Comment: Maybe you have two functions with the same name.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that will allow us to reproduce the problem

Comment: @Cooper - the minimal reproducible example is above in the code.  A simple logging function.  No two functions have the same name.  All of the scripts were working for well over a year without issue and then last week, around Feb 7, they stopped working for no reason that I can tell.  No changes were made on my end.

Comment: @dataful.tech - The scopes have been set explicitly when they are required by the function.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with that function so it's not a reproducible example

Comment: The function works for me when I setup a one minute time based trigger

Comment: @Cooper I believe that's the point of my question.  The code is normal and sufficient, and you were able to get it to work.  The issue I am asking is has something changed with the installable (time-based) triggers?

Comment: Not on my account.  It works for me.  How did you create the trigger?

Comment: @Cooper In the Apps Script file I went to Triggers -> Add Trigger -> Selected Time-driven and then the appropriate time intervals.  I've tested a minute timer along with longer timers as well.  It never triggers the function and it never shows that the trigger even attempted to run.

Comment: Did you check the executions page

Comment: @Cooper - Yes, it unfortunately is empty except for the executions I initiated manually (which still work without issue).

Comment: I suggest moving to another container and try the same thing again.  Perhaps the container has been corrupted some how.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that caused this was related to Google Workspace's Context-Aware Access.  We had a location-based rule, and all of the Apps Script files were not listing a location, so they were failing the rule and being blocked.  Each Apps Script file had to be whitelisted in the API Controls of Google Workspace's Admin.  Doing so allowed the installable trigger to work properly again.